# Adobe flash professional color switch on frames

Tags: flash, actionscript

I need to make a simple app using adobe flash professional.

I have on frame 1 a red square and on frame 2 the same square blue.

When I press on that square I need to make the square blue, I mean I have to go to frame 2. This is like a color switch. 
Do you have any ideea? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each of your frames ensure the code

```
stop();
```

has been added.

Then, in your first frame add:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoFrame2);
function gotoFrame2(e:MouseEvent){
      gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Inside your second frame under 'stop()' add:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoFrame1);
function gotoFrame1(e:MouseEvent){
      gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

A safer option is to called you frames names in the properties panel, then in the gotoAndStop function you can call the string - this saves the potential glitches if you modify frame locations.

e.g:

```
gotoAndStop("MyHomePage")
```

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry - to be able to click on the square itself the Movie Clip must have an instance name (do this in the properties panel).

Then, instead of stage.addEventListener...-     use   - MovieClipName.addEventListener..

Answer (score 0):

Add "click" event listener on red aquare MovieClip and in handler do something like gotoFrame(2);